# iOS Swift Camera Picker transparent top and bottom

Tags: ios, swift, uiimagepickercontroller

Is it possible to make the camera picker look like how it looks when taking a video.

Here is how it is now:

[image]

I want to make it look more like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can't do exactly like the screenshot you provide with the UIImagePickerController, you will need to work directly with [AVFoundation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation) and  create a UI around a preview of the camera.

Apple explain the basics [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/cameras_and_media_capture) and multiple tutorials are available on the web like this [one](https://www.appcoda.com/avfoundation-swift-guide/) which will explain you everything you need to know about capturing still or lives photos.

**EDIT: You can manage to do it with UIImagePickerController**

You will need first to set showsCameraControls property to false. Then you need to add your own overlay with the cameraOverlayView property with your own controls (UIButton for example, it's a UIView) and then assigning the functions like takePictures() to your button to take a picture.

```
imagePicker.sourceType = .camera
imagePicker.showsCameraControls = false
imagePicker.delegate = self
imagePicker.cameraOverlayView = yourOverlayWithWithButtons
```

The camera preview will need to be transformed to be fullscreen (the 3x scale is to big but make the preview appear fullscreen at least on iPhone X, you can certainly improve that):

```
imagePicker.cameraViewTransform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 3, y: 3)
```

Be careful the Apple documentation for the cameraOverlayView property says:

> You can access this property only when the source type of the image picker is set to UIImagePickerController.SourceType.camera. Attempting to access this property for other source types results in throwing an invalidArgumentException exception.

Take a look at the Apple documentation on [UIImagePickerController](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiimagepickercontroller), [cameraOverlayView](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiimagepickercontroller/1619113-cameraoverlayview) and [showCameraControls](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiimagepickercontroller/1619129-showscameracontrols).

Answer (score 0):

by setting the imagePicker.cameraViewTransform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1.5, y: 1.5) only I was able to get the right effect I was looking for.